# web api route not found when calling from .net core app

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-web-api-routing

This is my controller - using webApi framework 4.6.1. It registers correctly, but when i send an ajax request from my .net core1.1 application i get a 404 error on both the get and the post methods.

```
  public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}


public class MainController : ApiController
{

        /// <summary>
        /// ExistingItems - keep a list of all items that are currently in 
         the list and were not processed, for auditing.
        /// </summary>
        public List<XMLData.Struct> ExistingItems = new List<XMLData.Struct>
        ();

        [Route("api/Main/GetMyList")]
        [ActionName("GetMyList")]
        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetMyList()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage resp = new HttpResponseMessage();
            resp.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
            return resp;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// PostXMLFile - process the xml file on the server.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value"></param>  
        [Route("api/Main/SaveXML/")]
        [ActionName("SaveXml")]
        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage SaveXml(string value)
        {
            List<XMLData.Struct> pageElements = ConvertToList(value);


            var url = "/resource/BigBearNew.xml";
            var path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(url);
            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.Load(path);
            foreach (var pge in pageElements)
            {
                if (!ElementExists(xDoc, pge))
                {
                    AddAsNew(xDoc, pge);
                };
            }

        HttpResponseMessage resp = new HttpResponseMessage();
        resp.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        return resp;  // OK = 200

    }
```

Here are the .net core1.1 calls. I have the WebApi project referenced in the .net core project.

```
function saveElementList()
{
$.ajax({
    url: 'api/Main/SaveXml',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(elementNodes),
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Saved successfully");
    }
});
}

function getList() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'api/Main/GetMyList',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   // data: JSON.stringify(elementNodes),
    success: function (data) {
        alert("got list successfully");
    }
});
}
```

I've check the routes and the attributes on the controller and they look like they are correct. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see where .NET Core fits into this. I see a Web API 2 application on .NET Framework, and I see some AJAX calls.

Comment: Can you hit the end points from the browser?

Comment: Are you using the same port between webapi and core (default is 5000) ?

Comment: Are you sure you need "GetMyList" in the route if you have it in the action name?

Comment: Try removing ending `/`  from `[Route("api/Main/SaveXML/")]` ?

Comment: Yes. no change. my WebApi is referenced in my core projected, and so is Microsoft.NetCore.App

Answer (score 0):

There were a few items i found with more digging.

1. It was a CORS issue. Once i added:
     **var enableCorsAttribute = new EnableCorsAttribute("*",
                                              "Origin, Content-Type, Accept",
                                              "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
     config.EnableCors(enableCorsAttribute);**

   to the WebApiConfig, I was able to use my test get function to test that it was getting to the server. Also my data on the ajax call was not configured correctly with the server side.

Last, the url to the WebApi was not correct. I needed to furnish the whole url with the port number.

Thanks for every ones help.

Comment: As mason remarked, this has nothing to do with dotnetcore.